# Arithmetic operation on very large static arrays in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, static, stack

I am new to `High Performance Computing` and my first question in this forum where I have been a reader for much long.

Basically I need to do arithmetic operations on very large arrays like  for instance

```
double variable [9][4][300][300][300] (uninitialized)
```

**case 1:** If I declare the array above as `local/automatic` then I get run-time error  if I had compiled without optimization *like*  "`g++ file.cpp`"  .. (the error is segmentation fault -- stack overflow???)

**case 2:** In the same case as above if I had compile with optimization the code runs as expected. `"g++ -O2 file.cp`p" (is the `array` in `bss` now???)

**case 3:** If I make the variable `global/static` then it compiles fine but nonetheless it does not run and just gives a message "`killed`" on terminal and terminates.

There is no real problem but I am curious and want to learn what happens when extremely large arrays are declared and where do they reside in memory depending on their data type.

I am also aware of the method of generating these arrays at run-time using malloc or new. Then of course it would be on heap.

So the most important question for me is --> which is the most efficient method (i.e. smallest run-time during computation of arrays in memory) of dealing with large arrays when compiling with `g++` and running on `linux clusters`.

Thank you for your patience for reading.

Comment: That array is pure insanity.  You need to use a more intelligent solution to process that amount of data unless your target platform is some sort of beastly machine.  Since that seems to not be the case, stream the data from disk in chunks or something similar.

Comment: These arrays are unavoidable. They represent variables in 4 dimensional space. And the memory operations solve complex non linear differential equation. And eventually the code will run on a cluster of 50 nodes with more than 100 gb memory. The data is indeed read from disk. My curiosity is in understanding where this data is located at run-time and which section (bss/stack/heap) would give fastest run time performance.

Comment: I would really suggest you to do your work based on some mathematical libraries like armadillo or BLAS. ANY THING you do and I mean ANY THING, its impossible to beat the performance of these libraries. Consider using them right from the begining :)

Comment: @physicist: The *data* is unavoidable, the storage and processing approach is not.  Like I said, storing that array *in your executable* is a non-starter unless you can make the assumption that your code will only ever be run on a machine which can handle it.  Since that is not the case, you have to change your approach.  You can store the data on disk and read chunks at a time.  Break it down, process it, store relevant information and read the next chunk.

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel here. If you're new to this kind of computing then you want to use something to make it all as painless as possible. Two non-linear partial differential equation libraries i've worked with/on are http://www.dealii.org/ and http://libmesh.sourceforge.net/ and they may do what you need (including cluster support etc). If they don't there are many similar libraries out there.

Comment: thank you folks:).  I am aware of BLAS and I need to see about your other suggestions. I would definitely get more information about them.

Comment: An 8 GB executable file? Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Local variables will *always* be on the stack, no matter optimization flags. And that array will be around 7 gigabyte! Way larger than any possible stack.

The size may also be a reason it doesn't start, as if you put it as a global/static variable then you need to have more than 7 GB or virtual memory *free* and *contiguous* to be able to even load the program.

Comment: So for case 2 (from the question) the array is still in stack. I thought the stack has a size limit of 8kb? Did I understand you right? I did not give any compile time option to increase stack limit.

Comment: Unless the variable is optimized away, then it's nowhere.

Comment: @physicist The stack on most modern systems is in the range one to four megabytes. There might be flags you can pass to the linker for certain system to change it, but then the stack will be that size for the whole program and most of the time only a fraction (probably less than half a percent of that 7GB) will be used. A massive waste of memory. There are better ways to handle large datasets on a normal home-PC, like memory-mapping a file for example.

Comment: @BenVoigt Just curious, what does nowhere mean in this case? Like some new section? other than the usual bss, stack etc

Comment: @Joachim isn't it the case that (for single-threaded programs anyway) the stack and the heap grow towards each other from opposite ends of the virtual address space?  If so, then a single-threaded program will have stack space limited only by physical RAM.  (Of course that goes out the window when there are multiple threads, as you have to put each thread's stack somewhere in the process's virtual address space and so you have to start making assumptions about each thread's maximum expected stack usage)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that is interesting I never though of that. And I had read somewhere on net that stack only grows like federal budget :).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Maybe the best method is to dynamically allocate and free on heap. Would give fastest time compared to stack or bss?  Or if anyone could direct me to more reading references about this?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The amount of physical memory have not been a limitation in many years, it's all virtual (on home PCs at least). How the layout of stack versus heap is these days on modern PC operating systems I don't know, but it _used_ to be as you say, with stack and heap growing towards each other, however I kind of doubt it works like this on modern systems.

Comment: @physicist: If the optimizing compiler detects that it can calculate results without using the array, it will eliminate it.  There won't be an array in your program anymore.

Comment: @physicist Stack versus BSS versus DATA versus heap is not a factor for "speed". Especially since it's all going to be put in the CPU caches anyway.

Comment: @BenVoigt i see! i think i can check that on run time by seeing how much memory the program is occupying.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  That's what I wanted to hear :). SO there wont be any apparent advantage in using heap for large arrays. But I somehow get the feeling purists would frown at such abusive usage of stack like I am doing right now.

Comment: @physicist: Although such large data structures aren't any programmer's first choice, if you need them, the heap is designed to make it work.  OTOH automatic and global variables aren't designed to support such large sizes.

Comment: @BenVoigt  I agree... and got some wisdom from all this discussion. thank you everyone!!

Comment: With that size of the array, you must compile for and run on a 64bit platform as on a 32bit platform the amount of addressable memory per process is <4GiB

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest something along the lines of:

```
typedef double slice[300][300][300];

std::vector<slice> variable[9] = { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
```

This way each vector of 4 `slice` objects will be dynamically allocated, the contents of the 9 vectors need not be contiguous with each other, and the stack consumption is only enough for metadata for 9 vectors.

Comment: that is an interesting approach. let me try and see that. thank you.