# Problem with creating a large empty 2D array of strings in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, stack

I'm struggling with creating a large empty 2D array of strings (120000x7).

I created empty matrix like this:

`string large_matrix[120000][7] = {};`

If I create this array, it throws me a stack overflow exception. Does anyone know how to handle this problem? I do not want array as vector.

Comment: `auto large_matrix = std::make_unique<std::array<std::arrray<std::string>,7>,2000>();` This will prevent it from being created on the stack. And still be contiguous in memory (I assume you don't want vector because of non-locality)

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15803291/10871073